# Macbook pro 13 inch-2017 Apple Logo turns red when wake up from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

- **External Monitor connected:**
  When I wake up from sleep the logo appears in white colour with the red colour background with a progress bar below.
- **Without External Monitor:**
  When I wake up from sleep the logo appears in white colour with a progress bar below.

[image: Check this link to get an idea]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Your post is more a statement than a question...are you asking why this happens, or how to prevent this from happening? Could you add the following information to your question? 1) Do you experience other display issues apart from the one you describe? 2) How is the external monitor connected (which connector type, do you use an adapter, which model/manufacturer)? 3) Since when is this happening (update, upgrade, repair? 4) Which is your macOS version?

Comment: - How to prevent this?
- No Display issues other than this 
- Connected using HyperDrive USB-C to HDMI converter
- Actually didn't remember from when this is happening form last few months
- Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4